# Pointers to structures

Tags: c, pointers

The output has to be

```
 Student Number: 93745;
 Grade Point Ave:2.9;
 Sex (M or F):'M';
```

but I could not get those required output, Please point the mistake in the code and help to solve it, Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h> 
struct student {
 int num;    
 double gpa;
 char sex;   
};

void printstudent(struct student *p); /* prototype */

int main() {
/* allocate storage and initialize it */
struct student joe,*kim;
kim=&joe;

kim->num = 93745;
kim->gpa = 2.9;   
kim->sex = 'M';   


printstudent(joe);

}


void printstudent(struct student *p) {
printf("Student Number: %i\n", p->num);
printf("  Grade Point Ave: %0.2f\n",p->gpa);
printf("  Sex (M or F): %c\n\n", p->sex);
}
```

Comment: `printstudent(joe);` should be `printstudent(&joe);`

Comment: Also, what's the point in using the `kim` variable at all?

Comment: Why does kim point at joe? Seems obfuscated..

Answer (score 2):

```
printstudent(joe);
```

tries to interpret `joe` (a value of type `struct student`) as a pointer. You need to pass `kim` or `&joe`.

Answer (score 0):

```
printstudent(joe);
```

should be

```
printstudent(kim);
```

or

```
printstudent(&joe);
```

since the function takes a **pointer** to the structure.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point out that there's no reason to use pointers here:

```
int main() {
  /* allocate storage and initialize it */
  struct student joe;

  joe.num = 93745;
  joe.gpa = 2.9;   
  joe.sex = 'M';   

  printstudent(joe);
  return 0;
}


void printstudent(struct student p) {
  printf("Student Number: %i\n", p.num);
  printf("  Grade Point Ave: %0.2f\n",p.gpa);
  printf("  Sex (M or F): %c\n\n", p.sex);
}
```

Will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your program gets rejected by an automated system that pedantically checks the output of the program to the expected output, you have the following problems:

1. The single quotes around the `M` for the sex output must be added by yourself. They will **not** be generated by the `%c` printf specifier.
2. The second and third line you print have more spaces in them than I can see in the required output (especially at the start of the line and after the colon)
3. You are not printing the expected semi-colons at the end of the lines.